# export metadata to create mysql table from excel using pentaho or php laravel

Tags: php, laravel, metadata, pentaho, database-metadata

i want to ask is it possible to create a SQL DDL create query MySQL table from information.schema columns that saved in excel file?

my metadata in an excel file is like:
[metadata](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7mXX9.png)

what i want is from that metadata, it is able to create a CREATE DDL Queries from that metadata like:

```
CREATE TABLE `dim_companies` (
`id_company` int unsigned NOT NULL,
`id_app` int unsigned NOT NULL,
`company_name` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
`address` text,
`created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
PRIMARY KEY (`id_company')
)
```

i'm currently using pentaho data integration to solve this problem and using php laravel to create the application but i still can't figure it out.

the solution using pdi or php laravel doesn't matter

thanks!

Comment: is this your answer?- https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1050/create-table-in-sql-server-using-excel-template/

Comment: it is very close to what i looking for, i want it to be applied to my php laravel application so i need something like that but using the php itself or pdi, not on that excel